# Adding individual numbers to a nested list

Tags: python, list, loops, list-comprehension, nested-lists

```
nested_list = [[20,21,22],[31,32,33],[42,43,44]] 
another_list = [1,2,3]
```

This is what I have tried

```
for row in nested_list:
    nested_list.append(another_list)
```

I would like to pop off the starting number and add it to the end of each list within the nested list.
I have tried using append and extend but have not had any success. Can anyone help me to reach the desired output below?

Desired Output:

```
 Desired_list = [[20,21,22,1],[31,32,33,2],[42,43,44,3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over the two lists in parallel, which you can do using `zip`. And then you need to append to `row`, not `nested_list`.

```
for row, item in zip(nested_list, another_list):
    row.append(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of `enumerate()` method:-

```
for x,y in enumerate(nested_list):
    y.append(another_list[x])
```

Now if you print `nested_list` you will get your desired output:-

```
[[20, 21, 22, 1], [31, 32, 33, 2], [42, 43, 44, 3]]
```